# Has the word/name Beelzebub ever had a diaeresis?

Tags: archaicisms, diaeresis

I recognize that the diaeresis is not in the common English language anymore, but I was wondering if Beelzebub was ever spelt Beëlzebub, as I have found quite recently that I was pronouncing Beelzebub incorrectly as I didn't realize that there was a vocal syllable split in between the two e's. Google is difficult with older archaïc spellings, so I decided that it was best to ask the experts, thanks ahead of time. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: I may just be confused, but your two spellings are both the same. (_I was wondering if Beelzebub was ever spelt Beelzebub..._) Is this autocorrect? Or am I crazy?

Comment: Yes I'll fix it now

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beelzebub Other sources have a wide variety of spellings.

Comment: For what it's worth: Googling ["Beëlzebub" -"Beelzebub"] gets over 40,000 hits. Wiktionary and several other dictionary sites list the spelling with the diaeresis.

Comment: @DanielAsimov: in fact your search term gets 103 hits - and reports *"In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 103 already displayed."*

Comment: Maybe *your* googling has that result. Mine has the result I reported, which I just repeated now.

Answer (score 6):

The name *Beelzebub* has had a number of spellings over time, so it's quite likely that some authors have used *diaeresis* (the diacritic dots above a vowel marking the separation of two vowels in adjacent syllables) in spelling the word. But the usage would be rare.

In Middle English, the word more commonly only had a single vowel near the start, and hence spelled the word *belzebub* and variants ([Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED4024/track?counter=1&search_id=22841292)). Even after Middle English, pronunciation commonly follows a single vowel model: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Beelzebub) lists a single vowel among its acceptable pronunciations.

In the early modern period and thereafter, the double-e form from Latin is more often retained in English (compare Latin *Beëlzebūb*) and literate folk shift to "Bee-el-ze-bub" in pronunciation. In my experience, the diaeresis does not often appear to mark pronunciation. However, if you want to see examples of multiple variations, look at editions of *Paradise Lost*. For example, one can see the diaeresis you asked for in this moment from an 1850 edition of *Paradise Lost* ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Milton_s_Paradise_Lost/4dX8e__-glkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=be%C3%ABlzebub&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover)):

[image]

However, this form is absent from a much earlier edition of *Paradise Lost*. For instance, it does not appear in an early edition from 1674 ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Paradise_Lost/s6JEnFa--hkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Beelzebub)):

[image]

I'm used to seeing *Paradise Lost* editions like this, with no diaeresis. (I can't cite every edition I've seen, but [this *Oxford University Press*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Major_Works/Q0xkC5CEhHQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Beelzebub) edition from 2003 is typical.) That said, a *diaeresis* appears on *both* vowels in this 1669 edition ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Paradise_Lost_A_Poem_in_Ten_Books/w1dpAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Beelzebub)):

[image]

It is ultimately a printer's choice whether they choose to render diacritics in English or otherwise disambiguate pronunciation. At least before digital printing, most printers did not introduce diacritics; they weren't going to use a whole other [e] block with a diacritic in their usual typeset, at least in English. Unless the printer takes it upon themselves to render the mark, the diaeresis is invisible, a hidden tell for who had learned the pronunciation from an expert guide and who had only ever read the name.

The diacritic may appear more often in handwriting, and I'll return to this answer if I come across an example in a manuscript. But even then, much writing would follow printed spelling.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful reply!

Comment: @AlexBair See also the paywalled [OED entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/16978). It has a long etymological note.

Comment: The name occurs four times in Milton's poem, and in all four cases the meter demands its pronunciation in four syllables (two iambs). A diaeresis thus can usefully prevent readers from stumbling, especially when reading aloud. And given Milton's fondness for syntactic surprises, such readers need all such help they can get.